# How to test a view that creates a new team (entity) in a database?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have to unit test my current project and I've hit a roadblock. I'm at 85% coverage and I need to complete this test to go further. Basically, I need to test that my view is able to create a new team in my database. The Team Model is nested under an Organization in the form of a foreign key.

models.py -

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    orgname = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.orgname)

class Team(models.Model):
    teamID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    teamName = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teamName)
```

views_admin.py -

```
@csrf_exempt
def newTeam(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    param = json.loads(request.body)
    orgname = param.get('org')
    team = param.get('team')
    org = Organization.objects.get(orgname = orgname)
    print(org)
    Team.objects.create(teamName=team, org=org)
    return JsonResponse({'status':200})
```

urls.py -

```
path('ajax/newTeam/', views_admin.newTeam, name='ajax_newTeam'),
```

I have tried this so far:

```
def test_newTeam(self):
    params = {'orgname': REVCYCSCH, 'teamName': 'BLR Scheduling Eng'}
    response = self.client.post(path = '/ajax/newTeam/', data = params, content_type = 'application/json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But I get this error -

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: You first need to create the organization

Comment: Okay, so I added this line:

`Organization.objects.create(orgname='REVCYCSCH')`

But I still get the same error.

Comment: You're passing `orgname` in your params but looking for `org` in your view

Comment: big mistake. In unittest you need to mock all the packages including django models. Mock db object

Comment: @lalithkumar if you're a purist about doing only _unit_ testing, yes - but integration tests are useful too, and it's better to have integration tests than no test at all - at least you have a test ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As lalithkumar mentions, what you wrote is actually more of an integration test than a proper unit test - a proper unit test would directly call the view function with a handmade `request` object and [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the model layer.

Now note that this is not a bad thing in itself - integration tests have their use too, and in this case your test reveals a flaw in your view code and your API spec: you're not handling the case where the organisation doesn't exist - actually, you do not handle any error case at all.

IOW, you **do** want to keep this test - and possibly add other tests submitting other invalid data -, and check that you get a 4XX status code (4xx => bad request) and some error details in your json.

Also, for the nominal case (team successfully created), you may want to return a [201 Created](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-201-created/) instead (as the [response status](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#id3), not within the json itself !), with a link to the newly created team in the json content.

NB: of course if you don't mock the model layer you have to create the Organization instance in your db before the `client.post()` call.

**EDIT**:

> Could you tell me how to call the view function with a handmade request object and mock the model layer?

For the first point you want Django's [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/) - beware that it can be a bit of a pain to setup. wrt/ mocking, I already linked to the relevant doc. I'm not going to give you a detailed example because it would take much more time than I can afford (and there are some literature on the topic already).

This being said, in your case, I wouldn't bother with it ATM (until your mentor asks for "proper" unit testing, but that's a lot of work since you have to unittest *all* involved components in isolation, each time with all corner cases - and __still_ write integration tests above).

Your current integration test may not please purists, but it's still effective - it does test the whole chain, and as I said, it already revealed a major issue with your implementation: the complete lack of error handling. In real life programs, it's quite common to have three times more code dealing with errors / corner cases / unexpect conditions than what's actually needed to deal with the nominal case.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed reply!
But all I was asked to do is to just unit test. 
Could you tell me how to call the view function with a handmade request object and mock the model layer?
That is all I need to do, actually. 
I'm an intern and at this point, we aren't required to get into such in-depth testing.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! Appreciate it